# Can't mass-assign protected attributes devise error when using nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I have searched for quite a long, but could not found the solution. Here are my models:

*web.rb*

```
class Web < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_type, :remember_me

  belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true
end
```

*user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :web, :as => :role
 attr_accessible :dob, :fname, :lname
end
```

*org.rb*

```
class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :web, :as => :role
  attr_accessible :name, :website
end
```

Everything seems fine until i use the simple_form_for instead of normal form_for in the devise/registration/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :email, label: false, :input_html => { :class => "span6", placeholder: "Email", type: "email", required: true}%>

  <%= f.input :password, label: false, :input_html => { :class => "span6", placeholder: "Password", type: "password" }%>

  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: false, :input_html => { :class => "span6", placeholder: "Re-enter Password", type: "password" }%>

  <%= f.input :user_type, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => user_type} %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for resource.role do |rf| %>
    <%= render :partial => "#{child_class_name.underscore}_fields", :locals => { :f => rf } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
<% end %>
```

The nesting part puts the partial with appropriate model_fields name which contains corresponding fields.

*_org_fields.html.erb*

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"span6", :type=>"text", :placeholder=>"Name", :required=>"" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :website, :class=>"span6", :type=>"text", :placeholder=>"Website", :required=>"" %>
```

The problem is with the f.simple_fields_for, if i remove simple_ everything works fine. But i don't want it to be removed. The error i encounter is:

```
 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

 Can't mass-assign protected attributes: org
```

The request parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"NnsyNdrrKJmd8QutqVs6HqZi0EnQmAmZF7zGYqnu+rI=",
 "web"=>{"email"=>"",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "user_type"=>"org",
 "org"=>{"name"=>"",
 "website"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

Please Help.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: @Philip7899 I don't know about OP, but I'm using rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 1):

In `Web`, add:

```
attr_accessible :role_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :role
```

Edit: Originally had it as `User` but Devise resource is `Web`.

Edit2: Missed the `as: :role`. Changed the attr values to reflect.

Comment: That didn't help. I still have the same problem.

Comment: My original answer had them under User, not Web. Did you try it under Web?

Comment: Now i have this: No association found for name `org'. Has it been defined yet?

Comment: Made another edit. I missed the `as:` in the belongs_to association. Try now with my edit.

Comment: Now the original error came up. Can't mass-assign protected attributes: org

Comment: Hm. I'm not even sure where the org attribute is. I don't see it on any of your model definitions. Seeing that rendering all resource.roles as partials, is there another model that you haven't provided that has the org attribute?

Comment: The org attribute is passed internally as params based on the links user has clicked.

Comment: I think I might be expecting too much out of Rails for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method to automatically map to the polymorphic associations. Try just adding `org_attributes`, `user_attributes` to the `attr_accessible` list on `Web` and the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :org, :user` on `Web`. See how that goes.

Comment: This is what came up: `No association found for name org'. Has it been defined yet? (ArgumentError)`